# How to get target table in sync using Merge

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

How to get table in sync using Merge.

I have two tables: `Source` and `Target`. I want `Target` table to be in sync with `Source` after the query has completed.

Following are the columns for both tables. I want all columns except `Contact_no` to be in sync with `Target` table.

Initially I will copy 3 columns data into `Target` table where `Action = 'I'`.

### Source Table

```
Unique_ID   Part_no     Country_Code Contact_no
1           123             IN        12121212
2           456             US        65467987  
3           678             CH        65465465
4           897             EN        56546544
```

### Target Table

```
Unique_ID   Part_no     Country_Code    Action
1           123             IN            I
2           456             US            I 
3           678             CH            I
4           897             EN            I
```

After the SQL runs it will update, insert or delete `Target` table as per `Source` table with regard to `Action` flag.

### Next Day Source Table changed

```
Unique_ID   Part_no     Country_Code Contact_no
1           123             US        12121212  -- Updated Country_Code as "US"
2           456             US        65467987  -- No Change
3           678             CH        56565656  -- Deleted from Source
4           897             EN        56546544  -- No Change
5           114             DL        11111111  -- New Inserted
```

### Target Table

```
Unique_ID   Part_no     Country_Code    Action
1           123             US            U
2           456             US            I 
3           678             CH            D     -- Deleted from Source
4           897             EN            I
5           114             DL            I     -- Newly Inserted
```

I have written below Merge statement but its not working properly, after initial insert with `Action` flag "I", when I execute, it is updating all the records with action flag as "U" even though I have updated only one record in `Source` table.

```
MERGE INTO Target d2
USING (SELECT Unique_id, Part_no, Country_code 
       FROM Source
       UNION ALL
       SELECT a.Unique_id, a.Part_no, a.Country_code
       FROM Target a LEFT JOIN Source b ON a.Unique_id=b.Unique_id
       WHERE b.Unique_id IS NULL 
       ) d
ON (d2.Unique_id=d.Unique_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT(Unique_id, Part_no, Country_code, Action)
   VALUES(d.Unique_id, d.Part_no, d.Country_code, 'I')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET d2.Action = 'U', d2.Country_code = d.Country_code;
-- DELETE WHERE d2.loc='DELETE ME';
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Are you using Oracle database or _MySQL_ ? There is no PL/SQL in _MySQL_. And _SQL Developer_ has nothing to do with your question, even if you are using it to develop your code.

Comment: my bad, by mistake it was added, i am using Oracle database

Comment: Your inner UNION ALL query might be the culprit for this. Please try with only the LEFT JOIN query.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `union all` which adds `target` to the `source` set? Those rows match on `unique_id` so you update them to `'U'`.

Comment: I have added union because if any records are updated at Source table, i need them too. But i think only select will not be worked.